# bluetooth file transfer "there was an error"

Tags: bluetooth, android, transfer

I attempt to copy a file from my Ubuntu 20.04 machine to an Android phone via bluetooth. I follow the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-send-file.html.en
The devices are paired. After selecting the file to copy to the phone, there is the message "There was an error".

How do I diagnose this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the error message using:

```
journalctl -r -t obexd
```

which for example could be:

```
obexd: Transfer Error: Unsupported Media Type
```

which indicates that the file format is not accepted by the destination device (in this case the workaround would be: zip it and send the zip file).

Comment: One wonders why the text shown by journalctl could not have been displayed instead of the inane "There was an error"

Comment: Yep, that's annoying. The answer is that seems difficult to implement, more details here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-bluetooth/-/issues/4#note_280552

Answer (score 0):

I try to send a file created by an app I made from Android to PC and I have the same error. I closed the APP and problem persists. If I change the name of the file the problem is solved. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1238593)